# See the actual code for SageMaker model containers?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sagemaker

SageMaker model containers I believe are flask apps that run inside a container. I've deployed a few custom containers, but I'm wondering if I can see the actual code (docker file and all) for their exsisting algorithms? Would be helpful to understand in more detail what's happening inside during training/inference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a look at the containers for the different Frameworks as they are supported by Amazon SageMaker, you can check the GitHub:

- Deep Learning Containers: [Github Link](https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers)
- XGBoost Container: [Github Link](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-xgboost-container)
- SKLearn Container: [Github Link](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-scikit-learn-container)
- Spark Container: [Github Link](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-spark-container)

This should answer your question regarding dockerfiles, training and deployment.

The [built-in algorithms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/algos.html) in Amazon SageMaker (also called 1P algorithms) are part of AWS PI, so they are not publicly available.

Comment: OK had a feeling some of it would not be public - thanks for the links/answer!